# predict data for new group from gamboost model

Tags: r, prediction, boosting, generalized-additive-model

Suppose I have the following `mboost::gamboost` model:

`gamboost(resp ~ bbs(x1) + bols(x2) + brandom(x3), data = data)`

Suppose I have data I'd like to score, but that comes from new groups (i.e., new values of grouping variable `x3`). How do I use `predict.gamboost` for this prediction task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way `predict.mboost` handles this use case is that you must add the new identifiers as levels to the factor variable used in constructing the `brandom` base learner for the random effect. Then, you specify the new data, assigning the grouping variable to the new data `data.frame` as a factor variable with the same levels as the grouping variable used in constructing the model fit.

e.g.,

```
gammod <- gamboost(resp ~ bbs(x1) + bols(x2) + brandom(x3), data = data)
newdat <- data.frame(x1 = sample(x1min:x1max, n), x2 = sample(x2min:x2max, n),
                     x3 = as.factor(sample(x3min:m3max),
                     levels = levels(data$x3))
predictions <- predict(gammod, type = "response", newdata = newdat)
```